# Firefox web extension content script is not executed in newly created tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my Firefox web extension I am adding a new button to the browser toolbar which opens a small popup. Inside this popup a button is displayed which should create a new browser window, open a couple of URLs in new tabs and finally execute different content scripts on those pages.

My code looks like this

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Auto URL Opener",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "Auto URL Opener",
  "icons": { "48": "icon48.png" },

  "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": { "48": "icon48.png" },
    "default_title": "Auto URL Opener",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
         <button id="openUrlsButton">Open URLs</button>
         <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('openUrlsButton').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log('### create new window and open tabs');

    browser.windows.create({
        incognito: false,
        url: 'about:blank'
    }).then((window) => {
        console.log('### window created', window.id);

        browser.tabs.create({
            url: 'http://www.xkcd.com/',
            windowId: window.id
        }).then((tab) => {
            console.log('### tab1 created', tab.id);

            browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid green"'
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('### executed content script in tab1');  
            });
        });

        browser.tabs.create({
            url: 'http://www.google.com/',
            windowId: window.id
        }).then((tab) => {
            console.log('### tab2 created', tab.id);

            browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid blue"'
            });
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('### executed content script in tab2');  
        });
    });
}
```

My desired behavior is

- a new browser window is opened
- in the new browser window three tabs are opened

  - one with "about:blank" page
  - one with the xkcd website
  - one with the google website
- content script in tab with xkcd website is executed
- content script in tab with google website is executed
- the browser console shows 6 log messages

  - `### create new window and open tabs`
  - `### window created <window id>`
  - `### tab1 created <tab id>`
  - `### executed content script in tab1`
  - `### tab2 created <tab id>`
  - `### executed content script in tab2`

Actual behavior is

- a new browser window is opened
- in the new browser window three tabs are opened

  - one with "about:blank" page
  - one with the xkcd website
  - one with the google website
- content scripts are not executed
- the browser console shows 2 of 6 log messages

  - `### create new window and open tabs`
  - `### window created <window id>`

It feels like the execution of the code is interrupted when the new browser window is opened and the web extension popup is automatically closed.

When I re-factor my code the following way

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Auto URL Opener",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "Auto URL Opener",
  "icons": { "48": "icon48.png" },

  "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": { "48": "icon48.png" },
    "default_title": "Auto URL Opener",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
         <button id="openUrlsButton">Open URLs</button>
         <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('openUrlsButton').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({
        task: "open urls"
    });
}
```

background.js

```
function openUrls() {
    console.log('### create new window and open tabs');

    browser.windows.create({
        incognito: false,
        url: 'about:blank'
    }).then((window) => {
        console.log('### window created', window.id);

        browser.tabs.create({
            url: 'http://www.xkcd.com/',
            windowId: window.id
        }).then((tab) => {
            console.log('### tab1 created', tab.id);

            browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid green"'
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('### executed content script in tab1');  
            });
        });

        browser.tabs.create({
            url: 'http://www.google.com/',
            windowId: window.id
        }).then((tab) => {
            console.log('### tab2 created', tab.id);

            browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid blue"'
            });
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('### executed content script in tab2');  
        });
    });
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(openUrls);
```

I get the desired behavior but I am not sure if this is a good solution.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my question with full working code, more detailed description and desired/actual behavior.

Comment: @StigP.: I provided the solution, if it solves your problem, please accept the answer

Comment: @Sudarshan, IMO, it is inappropriate to be asking for acceptance less than a minute after posting an answer. In general, it is reasonable for OPs to wait a while before accepting an answer to see if other, potentially better, answers will be posted. Once an answer is accepted, it is *much* less likely that another answer will be posted. In this case, the edit that the OP made to the question to add complete code effectively makes it a brand new question (and now answerable).

Comment: @Sudarshan I'm aware that you answered after the question edit. That was not what I stated as my issue. I would suggest you read [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288) among many other posts on meta about asking for acceptance/up-votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Script 1

did not work because **code is placed in popup.js file**, Whose life time is dependent on how long the **web extension popup is open and active**

### Script 2

did work because the **code is placed in background.js file**, whose life time is dependent on how long the **extension is open and active**.

Script 2 approach is the correct method of solving the problem